# how to get executed a query of two tables of same columns to datagridview columns only once in c# and Sql

Tags: c#, sql, join, datagridview

I got a strange problem
I have 2 tables in sql database
So I want to write a query which gives result of 2 tables data
2 tables have same column names like

admission_number
student_name
student_class
I want to execute that query as given Image  [image]
The data which is got after executing query will be loaded to datagridview of win-form coding in C#
I'm traing this using as below code,but its completly not related to my Issue, please help me.

```
 private void report()
    {
        dataGridView4.AutoResizeColumns();
        dataGridView4.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;


        ConnectionStringSettings consettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["smssms"];
        string connectionString = consettings.ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        cn.Open();
        //pass query 

        sqlcmd = new
SqlCommand(@"selectt.admission_number,t.student_name,t.student_class,e.admission_number,e.student_name,e.student_class
from tenthclass_marks as t,eighth_to_ninth_marks as e ", cn);
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        //Fill the data in the SQL Data Adapter
        sda.Fill(dt);
        //Bind it in the DataGrid View
        dataGridView4.DataSource = dt;
        cn.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query as it stands:

```
select  t.admission_number,
        t.student_name,
        t.student_class,
        e.admission_number,
        e.student_name,
        e.student_class
from    tenthclass_marks as t,
        eighth_to_ninth_marks as e
```

is producing the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two tables. That is to say every row in `tenthclass_marks` is combining with every row `eighth_to_ninth_marks`, so if each table has 5 rows, you will end up with 25 rows (5 x 5).

You need to use `UNION ALL` to combine the results:

```
SELECT  t.admission_number,
        t.student_name,
        t.student_class
FROM    tenthclass_marks AS t
UNION ALL
SELECT  e.admission_number,
        e.student_name,
        e.student_class
FROM    eighth_to_ninth_marks AS e;
```

For what it is worth your c# can be cleaned up a bit too:

```
private void report()
{
    dataGridView4.AutoResizeColumns();
    dataGridView4.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["smssms"].ConnectionString;
    string sql = @"SELECT   t.admission_number,
                            t.student_name,
                            t.student_class
                    FROM    tenthclass_marks AS t
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT  e.admission_number,
                            e.student_name,
                            e.student_class
                    FROM    eighth_to_ninth_marks AS e;";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();     
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionString))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    dataGridView4.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **UNION ALL** Between your Two Tables

```
Select * from tenthclass_marks 
Union All 
Select * from eighth_to_ninth_marks
```